# bacgkgound-image css property doesn't fit the proportions on mobile devices

Tags: css, mobile, background-image

The code I have for an image:

```
.hero-image {
  background-image: url('hero.jpg');
  height: 620px;
  background-position: center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  -webkit-background-size: cover;
  -moz-background-size: cover;
  -o-background-size: cover;
  background-size: cover;
}
```

It works perfectly in Chrome devtools. Here is a screenshot:
[image]

But on my phone, the image doesn't look good:

[image]

Can't figure what's wrong with the code. I tested on several phones in several browsers. But the result is the same. Is there anything that can be done to solve the issue? Thanks.

Comment: I would experiment with using `background-size: contain` when you get to mobile viewports by using `@media` queries... It should scale a bit nicer as the viewport reduces. Without a working example, its hard to pinpoint your issue.

Comment: add some background-color to be sure It's because of background. I think background is not the reason. maybe z-index, overflow or something else.

Comment: If I use `background-size: contain` the image will be small